# How to shrink temp tablespace in oracle?

Tags: oracle

How can we shrink temp tablespace in oracle? And why it is increasing so much like upto 25 GB since there is only one schema in the database for the application and data table space size is 2 GB and index table space size is 1 GB used.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer and at the page it links to? I wonder what else you would need.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Oh My Goodness! Look at the size of my temporary table space!
Or... how to shrink temporary tablespaces in Oracle.

Yes I ran a query to see how big my temporary tablespace is:

```
SQL> SELECT tablespace_name, file_name, bytes
2  FROM dba_temp_files WHERE tablespace_name like 'TEMP%';

TABLESPACE_NAME   FILE_NAME                                 BYTES
----------------- -------------------------------- --------------
TEMP              /the/full/path/to/temp01.dbf     13,917,200,000
```

The first question you have to ask is why the temporary tablespace is so large.
You may know the answer to this off the top of your head.  It may be due to a 
large query that you just run with a sort that was a mistake (I have done that
more than once.)  It may be due to some other exceptional circumstance.  If that
is the case then all you need to do to clean up is to shrink the temporary
tablespace and move on in life.

But what if you don't know?  Before you decide to shrink you may need to do some
investigation into the causes of the large tablespace.  If this happens on a 
regular basis then it is possible that your database just needs that much space.

The dynamic performance view

```
V$TEMPSEG_USAGE
```

can be very useful in determining the cause.

Maybe you just don't care about the cause and you just need to shrink it. 
This is your third day on the job.  The data in the database is only 200MiB
if data and the temporary tablespace is 13GiB - Just shrink it and move on. 
If it grows again then we will look into the cause.  In the mean time I am
out of space on that disk volume and I just need the space back.

Let's take a look at shrinking it.  It will depend a little on what version
of Oracle you are running and how the temporary tablespace was set up.
Oracle will do it's best to keep you from making any horrendous mistakes
so we will just try the commands and if they don't work we will shrink
in a new way.

First let's try to shrink the datafile.  If we can do that then we get back
the space and we can worry about why it grew tomorrow.

```
SQL>
SQL> alter database tempfile '/the/full/path/to/temp01.dbf' resize 256M; 
alter database tempfile '/the/full/path/to/temp01.dbf' resize 256M
*   
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03297: file contains used data beyond requested RESIZE value
```

Depending on the error message you may want to try this with different sizes
that are smaller than the current site of the file.  I have had limited
success with this.  Oracle will only shrink the file if the temporary tablespace
is at the head of the file and if it is smaller than the size you
specify.  Some old Oracle documentation (they corrected this) said that
you could issue the command and the error message would tell you what
size you could shrink to.  By the time I started working as a DBA this was
not true.  You just had to guess and re-run the command a bunch of times
and see if it worked.

Alright.  That didn't work.  How about this.

```
SQL> alter tablespace YOUR_TEMP_TABLESPACE_NAME shrink space keep 256M;
```

If you are in 11g (Maybee in 10g too) this is it!  If it works you may want
to go back to the previous command and give it some more tries.

But what if that fails.  If the temporary tablespace is the default temporary
that was set up when the database was installed then you may need to do a
lot more work.  At this point I usually re-evaluate if I really need that
space back. After all disk space only costs $X.XX a GiB.  Usually I don't want
to make changes like this during production hours.  That means working at 2AM
AGAIN!  (Not that I really object
to working at 2AM - it is just that... Well I like to sleep too.  And my wife
likes to have me at home at 2AM...  not roaming the downtown streets at 4AM trying
to remember where I parked my car 3 hours earlier.  I have heard of that "telecommuting"
thing.  I just worry that I will get half way through and then my internet connectivity
will fail - then I have to rush downtown to fix it all before folks show up in the
morning to use the database.)

Ok... Back to the serious stuff...
If the temporary tablespace you want to shrink is your default
temporary tablespace, you will have to first create a new temporary
tablespace, set it as the default temporary tablespace then drop
your old default temporary tablespace and recreate it. Afterwords
drop the second temporary table created.

```
SQL> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp2
2  TEMPFILE '/the/full/path/to/temp2_01.dbf' SIZE 5M REUSE
3  AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1M MAXSIZE unlimited
4  EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 1M;

Tablespace created.

SQL> ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp2;

Database altered.

SQL> DROP TABLESPACE temp INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;

Tablespace dropped.


SQL> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
2  TEMPFILE '/the/full/path/to/temp01.dbf' SIZE 256M REUSE
3  AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 128M MAXSIZE unlimited
4  EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 1M;

Tablespace created.

SQL> ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;

Database altered.

SQL> DROP TABLESPACE temp2 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;

Tablespace dropped.
```

Hopefully one of these things will help!

Comment: Just a note -- SHRINK SPACE is introduced in 11g, and is not available in 10g. Thanks for a really thorough write-up of all the options!

Comment: Many posts and articles on the internet suggest very complicated procedures. This one was the simplest I've found!

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear and precise explanation and solution. It's the best one found on the Internet so far.

Comment: I agree, this answer is awesome and very helpful!  Thanks!

Thinking about it some more, I had a question - 

Would it be possible to just create a 2nd datafile under the temp tablespace, then take the orig datafile offline, drop it/recreate it, then take it back online?

It's a minor difference, but I'm wondering if keeping the tablespace would help or hinder the process?

Comment: the second approach (with temp2) may hang at "DROP TABLESPACE temp INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES" step on "enq: TS - contention" for a long time, if there are sessions that (not necessarily active) that are using it directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 6):

The options for managing tablespaces have got a lot better over the versions starting with 8i.  This is especially true if you are using the appropriate types of file for a temporary tablespace (i.e. locally managed tempfiles).

So, it could be as simple as this command, which will shrink your tablespace to 128 meg...

```
alter tablespace <your_temp_ts> shrink space keep 128M;
```

The Oracle online documentation is pretty good.  [Find out more.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces007.htm#CFHJFBBJ)

**edit**

It would appear the OP has an earlier version of the database.  With earlier versions we have to resize individual datafiles.  So, first of all,  find the file names.  One or other of these queries should do it...

```
select file_name from dba_data_files where tablespace_name = '<your_temp_ts>'
/

select file_name from dba_temp_files where tablespace_name = '<your_temp_ts>'
/
```

Then use that path in this command:

```
alter database datafile '/full/file/path/temp01.dbf'  resize 128m
/
```

Comment: SQL> alter tablespace temp shrink space keep 128M;
alter tablespace temp shrink space keep 128M
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02142: missing or invalid ALTER TABLESPACE option

Answer (score 2):

You should have written what version of Oracle you use. You most likely use something else than Oracle 11g, that's why you can't shrink a temp tablespace.

Alternatives:

1) `alter database tempfile '[your_file]' resize 128M;` which will probably fail
2) Drop and recreate the tablespace. If the temporary tablespace you want to shrink is your default temporary tablespace, you may have to first create a new temporary tablespace, set it as the default temporary tablespace then drop your old default temporary tablespace and recreate it. Afterwards drop the second temporary table created.
3) For Oracle 9i and higher you could just drop the tempfile(s) and add a new one(s)

Everything is described **[here](http://databaseguide.blogspot.com/2008/06/resizing-temporary-tablespace.html)** in great detail.

---

See this link: http://databaseguide.blogspot.com/2008/06/resizing-temporary-tablespace.html
It was already linked, but maybe you missed it, so here it is again.

Answer (score 1):

It will be increasing because you have a need for temporary storage space, possibly due to a cartesian product or a large sort operation.

The dynamic performance view `V$TEMPSEG_USAGE` will help diagnose the cause.

Comment: Another reason could be heavy usage of global temporary tables.

Comment: Yes, good point that. Or even the materialisation of subquery factoring clause result sets.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary tablespaces are used for database sorting and joining operations and for storing global temporary tables. It may grow in size over a period of time and thus either we need to recreate temporary tablespace or shrink it to release the unused space.

[Steps to shrink TEMP Tablespace](https://orahow.com/shrink-temp-tablespace-in-oracle/)

Answer (score 0):

```
alter database datafile  'C:\ORA_SERVER\ORADATA\AXAPTA\AX_DATA.ORA' resize 40M;
```

If it doesn't help:

- Create new tablespace
- Switch to new temporary tablespace
- Wait until old tablespace will not be used
- Delete old tablespace

Answer (score 0):

I don't bother with dropping the alternate temp in case i need to reclaim storage again in the future...

1. from temp group set default to stand-alone temp
2. wait awhile, then resize members of temp group
3. set default back to temp group
4. wait awhile, resize stand alone temp. there's no rush to do the last step