# ORA-01652 Unable to extend temp segment by in tablespace

Tags: oracle10g, tablespace

I am creating a table like

```
create table tablename
as
select * for table2
```

I am getting the error

```
ORA-01652 Unable to extend temp segment by in tablespace
```

When I googled I usually found ORA-01652 error showing some value like

```
Unable to extend temp segment by 32 in tablespace
```

I am not getting any such value.I ran this query

```
select 
   fs.tablespace_name                          "Tablespace", 
   (df.totalspace - fs.freespace)              "Used MB", 
   fs.freespace                                "Free MB", 
   df.totalspace                               "Total MB", 
   round(100 * (fs.freespace / df.totalspace)) "Pct. Free" 
from 
   (select 
      tablespace_name, 
      round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) TotalSpace 
   from 
      dba_data_files 
   group by 
      tablespace_name 
   ) df, 
   (select 
      tablespace_name, 
      round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) FreeSpace 
   from 
      dba_free_space 
   group by 
      tablespace_name 
   ) fs 
where 
   df.tablespace_name = fs.tablespace_name;
```

Taken from: [Find out free space on tablespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672126/find-out-free-space-on-tablespace)

and I found that the tablespace I am using currently has around 32Gb of free space. I even tried creating table like

```
create table tablename tablespace tablespacename
as select * from table2
```

but I am getting the same error again. Can anyone give me an idea, where the problem is and how to solve it. For your information the select statement would fetch me 40,000,000 records.

Comment: are you data files full?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found the solution to this. There is a temporary tablespace called TEMP which is used internally by database for operations like distinct, joins,etc. Since my query(which has 4 joins) fetches almost 50 million records the TEMP tablespace does not have that much space to occupy all data. Hence the query fails even though my tablespace has free space.So, after increasing the size of TEMP tablespace the issue was resolved. Hope this helps someone with the same issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Another approach that *can* help is to check if there is an alternative plan for the query that doesn't require so much temp space - e.g. by avoiding a sort or a merge. Not always easy or possible, of course.

Comment: And if you wonder how you can shrink your TEMP tablespace to fit the data, see this great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1878732/210114

Answer (score 7):

Create a new datafile by running the following command:

```
alter tablespace TABLE_SPACE_NAME add datafile 'D:\oracle\Oradata\TEMP04.dbf'            
   size 2000M autoextend on;
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a new datafile; you can extend your existing tablespace data files.

Execute the following to determine the filename for the existing tablespace:

```
  SELECT * FROM DBA_DATA_FILES;
```

Then extend the size of the datafile as follows (replace the filename with the one from the previous query):

```
  ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'D:\ORACLEXE\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM.DBF' RESIZE 2048M;
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message but don't have any access to the table like "dba_free_space" because I am not a dba. I use some previous answers to check available space and I still have a lot of space. However, after reducing the full table scan as many as possible. The problem is solved. My guess is that Oracle uses temp table to store the full table scan data. It the data size exceeds the limit, it will show the error.  Hope this helps someone with the same issue