# How could I update multiple columns in Oracle with same id?

Tags: database, oracle, select, set

I am new in Oracle SQL and I am trying to make an update of a table with the next context:

I have a table A:

```
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| ColumnA | name    | ColumnC | Column H |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| 1       | Harry   |  null   | null     |
| 2       | Harry   |  null   | null     |
| 3       | Harry   |  null   | null     |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
```

And a table B:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| name    | ColumnE | ColumnF |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Harry   | a       |  d      |
| Ron     | b       |  e      |
| Hermione| c       |  f      |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

And I want to update the table A so that the result will be the next:

```
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| ColumnA | name    | ColumnC | Column H |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| 1       | Harry   |  a      | d        |
| 2       | Harry   |  a      | d        |
| 3       | Harry   |  a      | d        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
merge into tableA a
using tableB b
on (a.name=b.name)
when matched then update set
columnC = b.columnE,
columnH = b.columnF


create table tableA (columnC varchar2(20), columnH varchar2(20), name varchar2(20), columnA number);
create table tableB (columnE varchar2(20), columnF varchar2(20), name varchar2(20));
insert into tableA values (null, null,'Harry',1);
insert into tableA values (null, null,'Harry',3);
insert into tableA values (null, null,'Harry',3);
insert into tableB values ('a', 'd','Harry');
insert into tableB values ('b', 'e','Ron');
insert into tableB values ('c', 'f','Hermione');
select * from tableA;
merge into tableA a
using tableB b
on (a.name=b.name)
when matched then update set
columnC = b.columnE,
columnH = b.columnF;
select * from tableA;
```

I got no error

Comment: i GET THE ERROR "Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis"

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post. In table A the name values are the same ("Harry", "Harry", "Harry"). So I want to populate the values of the columns C and H with the respective values according to the values on the columns E and F in table B, depending to the name value.

Comment: I've pasted you whoole code I've tested. It works. I got no error about parenthesis. Please check what are you executing

Comment: You're right! It workd! But now I am getting the next error: Error: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839576/ora-01652-unable-to-extend-temp-segment-by-in-tablespace
Check this. Probably you need to extend tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableA t1
SET (ColumnC, ColumnH) = (SELECT t2.ColumnE, t2.ColumnF
                     FROM table2 t2
                    WHERE t1.name = t2.name)
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
  FROM table2 t2
 WHERE t1.name = t2.name)
```

This should work. You can refer to this answer for more info:
[Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: I get the error: Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row. So how could I solve it?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post. In table A the name values are the same ("Harry", "Harry", "Harry"). So I want to populate the values of the columns C and H with the respective values according to the values on the columns E and F in table B, depending to the name value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use below query and update your table A.

Update all rows with 'a' and 'd';

```
update table A
set (columnC , columnh ) = (SELECT COLUMNE,COLUMNF 
                                      FROM TABLE B
                                   where b.name =a.name);
```

Alternatively you can also use:

```
UPDATE (SELECT   T2.COLUMNE COLE,                              
                 T2.COLUMNF COLF,
                 T1.COLUMNC COLC,
                 T1.COLUMNH COLH
        FROM tableB T2,
             tableA  T1
        WHERE T1.NAME = T2.NAME)        
SET COLC = COLE,
    COLH = COLF ;
```

and Output is :

```
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| ColumnA | name    | ColumnC | Column H |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| 1       | Harry   |  a      | d        |
| 2       | Harry   |  a      | d        |
| 3       | Harry   |  a      | d        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post. In table A the name values are the same ("Harry", "Harry", "Harry"). So I want to populate the values of the columns C and H with the respective values according to the values on the columns E and F in table B, depending to the name value.

Comment: Then it becomes more simple. Just update name in the first query..See edited.