# ORA-01652 - Query doen't work with hibernate but it works fine in SQL client

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, tablespace

I execute a SQL query with hibernate and the application give the error:

ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment

The TABLE SPACE has 4 GB.

The strange thing is that the query from the application yesterday was working fine, and today it doen't work.

I have not made any changes either in the database or application.

The oracle version is Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

You are running short on space in temp tablespace , use this query t check how much space you have in your temp tablespace

```
SQL> select file_name,SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 "Current_size_mb", sum(maxbytes)/1024/1024 "max_size_mb" from dba_temp_files group by file_name;

FILE_NAME                                                              Current_size_mb max_size_mb
---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- -----------
C:\AKS\AKDB\ORADATA\RESEARCH\TEMP01.DBF                                             20  32767.9844
```

Adding a new tempfile to temp tablespace

```
SQL> alter tablespace temp add tempfile 'C:\AKS\AKDB\ORADATA\RESEARCH\TEMP02.DBF' size 100m autoextend on maxsize 1g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary tablespace called TEMP which is used internally by database for operations like distinct, joins,etc to fetch large amount of data.

So, after increasing the size of TEMP tablespace the issue can be resolved.

**Follow this link** : [How to shrink temp tablespace in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824572/how-to-shrink-temp-tablespace-in-oracle/1878732#1878732)